# Partial derivative w.r.t. time of $v(t)=\sqrt{mg\over k} \tanh\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m})\right)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

This question is a follow on one from my question on [ICBM Dynamics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4553948/1107781) as since after correctly solving the equations for velocity and time I now need to take the partial derivative of the velocity equation to find acceleration.$${\partial v\over \partial t}={{\partial \left( \sqrt{mg\over k} \tanh\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right) \right)}\over \partial t}$$

I know enough about differential equations to know to factor out the constants and to recognize it is probably useful to split this as a chain $${\partial v\over \partial t}={{d \left( \sqrt{mg\over k} \tanh\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right) \right)}\over d \left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right)} \cdot {\partial \left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right)\over \partial t}$$ but don't know what to do any further (I am a Yr 12 student and only just new to this grade of calculus).

Two questions:

1. Does anyone have some comprehensive and easy to understand steps of how to solve this kind of equation?
2. Does anyone have any suggestions of some hyperbolic trig identities that could help me simplify  this problem.

EDIT:
@ David G. Stork, Thanks for your hint!

After looking at the problem as a group of 'substituted' constants it became much easier,
$${\partial v\over \partial t}={{\partial \left( \sqrt{mg\over k} \tanh\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right) \right)}\over \partial t}\\{\partial v\over \partial t}={{d \left( \sqrt{mg\over k} \tanh\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right) \right)}\over d \left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right)} \cdot {\partial \left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right)\over \partial t}\\$$
Using ${d\over d\theta}\left(\tanh(\theta)\right)=\operatorname{sech}^2(\theta)\\$:
$${\partial v\over \partial t}={\sqrt{mg\over k}}\cdot \operatorname{sech}^2\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right) \cdot \left({\partial \left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left(v_0 \sqrt{k\over mg}\right)\right)\over \partial t} - {{\partial t\sqrt{kg\over m}}\over \partial t}\right)\\$$
$${\partial v\over \partial t}={\sqrt{mg\over k}}\cdot \operatorname{sech}^2\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right) \cdot -\sqrt{kg\over m}\\$$
$${\partial v\over \partial t}=-g\cdot \operatorname{sech}^2\left(\operatorname{arctanh}\left( v_0\sqrt{k\over mg}\right)-t\sqrt{kg\over m}\right)$$

Comment: First, replace all constants with simple terms so you'll see the structure of the problem better.  Then straightforward application rules give:  $$v_0 \sqrt{\frac{m (x+1)}{k}} \sqrt{\frac{k}{m (x+1)}-t \sqrt{\frac{k (x+1)}{m}}}$$. Your problem term is:  $\tanh (\tanh^{-1}(a- t b))$.  See how much simpler that looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is of the form:  $$a \tanh(\tanh^{-1}(b - c t)) = a (b-c t)$$. Now the problem is trivial.

Comment: What is written in the title is $a\tanh(\operatorname{artanh}(b)-ct)$, which is more messy but still trivial

Comment: So does this mean that as above in the question the problem is $a\tanh(\operatorname{arctanh}(b) - ct)=a(b-ct)$ or something else. Also how would i write this 'simplification' in a proof